# Conditional matching of rows by iterating in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dfs.

df1

```
Date          Dollar  EURO  GBP
12/03/2019    100      80   90
12/02/2019    101      81   89
12/01/2019    1000     79   91
```

df2

```
Product   Currency  Rate   Date
ABC        EURO      80    12/03/2019
xyz        USD       105   11/30/2019
ert        GBP       90    11/29/2019
```

basically what I want is to place a new column(having rate of that currency and date) in df2 and further add a column if rate of df1 and df2 matches or not.

```
Product   Currency  Rate   Date          df1.rate     Check
ABC        EURO      80    12/03/2019    80           Match
xyz        USD       105   11/30/2019    N/A          Not Match
ert        GBP       90    11/29/2019    N/A          Not Match
```

I have tried .

```
USD = df2['Currency'] == "US $"
GBP = df2['Currency'] == "GBP"
EURO = df2['Currency'] == "EURO"

if USD:
    df2['Check'] = df2['rate'] == df1['Dollar']
elif GBP:
    df2['Check'] = df2['rate'] == df1['GBP']
elif EURO:
    df2['Check'] = df2['rate'] == df1['EURO']
```

it gives the following error on line 1.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Please suggest a remedy.

Comment: What have you tried? This exact question must have been asked dozens of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and `indicator` parameter, last set values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = df1.melt('Date', var_name='Currency', value_name='Rate')

df2 = df2.merge(df, how='left', indicator='Check')
mask = df2['Check'].eq('both')
df2['Check'] = np.where(mask, 'Match','Not Match')
print (df2)
  Product Currency  Rate        Date      Check
0     ABC     EURO    80  12/03/2019      Match
1     xyz      USD   105  11/30/2019  Not Match
2     ert      GBP    90  11/29/2019  Not Match
```

If need also column `df1.rate` add [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df2.insert(len(df2.columns)-1, 'df1.rate', df2['Rate'].where(mask))
print (df2)
  Product Currency  Rate        Date  df1.rate      Check
0     ABC     EURO    80  12/03/2019      80.0      Match
1     xyz      USD   105  11/30/2019       NaN  Not Match
2     ert      GBP    90  11/29/2019       NaN  Not Match
```

Explanation with details: Reshape values of `df1` for same format of data like `df2` by `melt`:

```
print (df1.melt('Date', var_name='Currency', value_name='Rate'))
         Date Currency  Rate
0  12/03/2019   Dollar   100
1  12/02/2019   Dollar   101
2  12/01/2019   Dollar  1000
3  12/03/2019     EURO    80
4  12/02/2019     EURO    81
5  12/01/2019     EURO    79
6  12/03/2019      GBP    90
7  12/02/2019      GBP    89
```

Then  `merge` with left join, indicator parameter create new column with info, if matching in both or left DataFrames:

```
print (df2.merge(df, how='left', indicator='Check'))
  Product Currency  Rate        Date      Check
0     ABC     EURO    80  12/03/2019       both
1     xyz      USD   105  11/30/2019  left_only
2     ert      GBP    90  11/29/2019  left_only
```

Last replace values by `mask`:

```
df2['Check'] = np.where(mask, 'Match','Not Match')
print (df2)
  Product Currency  Rate        Date      Check
0     ABC     EURO    80  12/03/2019      Match
1     xyz      USD   105  11/30/2019  Not Match
2     ert      GBP    90  11/29/2019  Not Match
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I a new to python. Can you please explain what this code is exactly doing.

Comment: @HusnainIqbal - Added some explanation, if someting is necessary explain more let me know

Comment: I just noticed that we are not specifying any columns to compare. How is it moving on? Can we specify columns?

Comment: @HusnainIqbal - yes, I omit it because it match by all columns, so it is same like `df2.merge(df, how='left', indicator='Check', on=['Date','Currency','Rate'])`

Comment: mine is not returning the desired result. but if i use non melted df1 it returns the right result. I am not getting it.

Comment: @HusnainIqbal - It is interesting, only reason should be format of `df1` input data is same like `print (df1.melt('Date', var_name='Currency', value_name='Rate'))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203516/discussion-between-husnain-iqbal-and-jezrael).